# Show that $\limsup_n \frac{S_n}{n(\log \log n)^{1-\epsilon}} = \infty$ with probability 1

Tags: probability, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas, bernoulli-distribution

Let $\{X_k\}$ be independent random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(X_k = k) = 1/k$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_k = 0) = 1-1/k$. Consider the sum $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$. Show that for any $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, with probability $1$,
$$
\limsup_n \frac{S_n}{n(\log \log n)^{1-\epsilon}} = \infty.
$$
I am trying to use Borel-Cantelli, but I have trouble constructing a sequence of independent events. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like this should follow from Kolmogorov's zero-one law.

Comment: @Math1000 I tried to estimate $\mathbb{P}(S_n\geq n (\log \log n)^{1-\epsilon})$. I can get an upper bound of this probability and it goes to $0$. So I am not sure if 0-1 law can be used.

Comment: Do you still concern above question? If  I  give an answer using LIL a week later.

Comment: @JGWang I got a hint: prove that there is $p>0$ such that for $0<r<1$ and for large enough $n$, $\mathbb{P}(\exists k_0\in [n,2^r n), X_k>0 \text{ and } \forall k\in [n,2^r n)\backslash \{k_0\}, X_k=0)\geq rp$. But I am not able to use it.

Comment: @bdl10 Thank you for your replication, I will consider the hint.